# current limiter / short circuit indicator for a variable power supply

Tags: power-supply, short-circuit

I am building a variable power supply circuit and I am wanting to add a current limiter or a short circuit protector to its output. I feature that I'm attempting to add to the protector is an indicator of load resistance that falls below a certain threshold. To be more specific, the power supply is run from a 12VDC power source and has an LM350 voltage regulator. The output is narrowed between 3-5VDC. The load will vary between 1.8 to 2.5 ohms. The load on average will be 2.2 ohms. The load on the power supply will be 3 amps. It is to run between 1.7 - 2.4 amps normally. I am having trouble searching for a circuit to handle this without having to use HUGE transistors or resistors due to space constraints. It would have a green LED and a red LED. If the load on the circuit is within 1.8 to 2.5 ohms then the operation is normal and the green LED is lit. If the load falls below 1.8 ohms, the load is either cut or is used to have the red LED lit. I first felt that it would look similar to the circuit found at:

[Power supply short circuit protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/power-supply-short-circuit-protection?rq=1)

but finding an SK100 transistor apparently is not easy or I have to substitute it with a physically large transistor. I am currently using gEDA to design the circuit but can't seem to make heads or tail of NGSpice or GNUCap to test and adjust the circuit (or I simply don't know how to use them properly) and have only contemplate almost having to learn another programming language to use them. Some of the free online graphical simulators have given either vague or inconclusive results.  One of the schematics that I have put together is the same PS with a different circuit protector. At this time, I'm sure it's calculations may be off. Can anyone point me in the right direction to help solve this or suggest a better protector circuit? Many thanks in advance.

[image: 3-5VDC_adj_psu]

Comment: What if I told you that a transistor to act as a high side current limiter/protection can be a very small SOT23 P-channel FET? For the given current (<=3A)

Comment: What if I told you that a 0.1 or even 0.01 Ohm current shunt resistor and a very small SOT23-5 Op-amp could be used as a comparator to drive a red or green LED to indicate load state?

Comment: @KyranF I'm certain that I'd believe you on that matter. The circuit was designed based on older electronics and I'm sure that the principles are the same but component designs have advanced a great deal. I'm Just uncertain where to start. At this point, the posted circuit is not the perfect design.

Comment: @KyranF During my search, I had noticed that some designs used N-FETs or P-FETs to handle the load but wasn't certain on how to fit in the visual indicators. I was under the assumption that the load was to be cut from the supply and the state of the circuit would remain that way until the load which fell below threshold was corrected. Now, I see fold back limiters in some of the designs but without indicators. Perhaps I'm not searching the correct criteria?

Comment: Well PFETs are sort of easier to design as high side power switches, because NFETs need a charge-pump or voltage doubler to get their gate above the source voltage (can be difficult at high voltages). You would need a complex circuit with load shunt resistors in there as well, to maintain knowledge of the load once you "turn it off" during a fault condition.

Comment: and to do the signal for the LED (red in fault, green in non-fault). You can use comparators with adjustable hysteresis to set the load cut-off condition and the condition that it returns to normal - this is sort of how fold-back current limiters work once they begin, you need to return the load to something much larger than the tripping point before normal operation resumes.

Comment: @KryanF The PFET design was a lot easier to work with. The example circuit in wikipedia under 'Mosfet' worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]  Here is a redrawn circuit with a Lm321 IC used as the current limit detector.
The output from the detector could also go to the gate of a SCR, with the Anode going to pin 1 of your regulator and the cathode tied to ground, killing the current regulator output. 
I designed and used this circuit in a cnc stepper motor driver circuit.

Use 0.1 ohm resistor at 3 Watts and  2.2k (1/4 to 1/2) watt. A 2N5060 is a sensitive gate low current SCR. The output Voltage may not go to zero volts but it will be close enough to Stop most current flow. You are right their is a minimum current requirement to keeping an SCR Latched. A simple test put an SCR on pin 1 Anode and Cathode to ground then trigger the gate. If it holds it will work. The gate will trigger just by touching it with your finger. Yes the SCR will stay latched until the 12 volts goes to Zero, or a momentary NC switch is installed between the Cathode and Ground. 2N5060 Low Holding Current = 5 mA Maximum Current Require to keep latched.

A transistor circuit will work if it is stabilized with a capacitor, values I am no sure of, That would have to be experimented with, otherwise the voltage will oscillate between high and low.

[image]

Comment: That's a great start! One question about using the SCR to short the LM350 pin to ground. The adjustment pin of the LM350 according to the datasheets states that the typical current draw to 50uA and 100uA max. Most of the SCR's I am seeing afford a great number of AMPS for their operation limits. Is it safe to guess that the current draw by shorting the adjust pin to ground depends on VOLTSout - VOLTSin difference? I'm not sure I have understood the data correctly But, once the SCR's gate is triggered, it will stay latched until the circuit is reset or powered off, correct?

Comment: Are there SCR's that handle very small current if the adjust pin current is small and may come in a TO-92 instead of a TO-220? I'm certain that a PNP / NPN pair can be used to subtitute if needed. Can a transistor (selection depends on the current / volts traversing the adjust pin to ground) be used instead to prevent the persistent latching once the comparator's high output goes low?

Comment: What are the ratings of the .1 and 2.2k ohm resisters next to the 2.2 ohm load resister? I have an inclination that the .1 ohm may need to be quite large.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the resistors. I breadboarded a mock-up of the comparator circuit using a 741 op amp until an LM321 arrives. Once I calculate the output from the LM321 (from the 4.7k ohm feedback resistor/500 variable on the inverting input and the 2.2k ohm / .22 ohm resistors on the non inverting input, I will be able to calculate how much (or how much to reduce) the bias from the LM321 output to 2N5060 SCR. Datasheets are a huge help. I will do some more tweaking later to get near exact measurements.

Comment: For some reason the edit I made did not take, Their should be a capacitor of 1uf going to ground on each of the op amps + and - inputs. Both could be from 5 to 100 volts DC.  Positive + side to op amp inputs.

Comment: I had grabbed a copy of it when you first posted it. I edited your post to put it back in.

Comment: It appears that I've run into a problem with the design. I added an SCR to short circuit the regulator's adjust pin to ground. This in turn drops the output to near 0 volts. The result is the power is removed from the load resistor but without a power passing through the load resistor to feed the comparator, it cannot fault the circuit to trigger the SCR. Sort of like a catch 22. Anyone have any advise on this?

Comment: @Remembermyname is that because now the input to the comparator is effectively floating? Usually using a 1 megaohm shunt resistor, you can tie that node to the power rail or ground to allow it to continue sensing the input despite the main power being removed from the load, or you can put a very high value shunt resistor in parallel (1 megaohm again?) with the FET which is switched off (so it still has a path, just not low resistance, so no 'power')

Comment: I have tried to upload a new Circuit including the SCR hook up, but it will not upload to this site.    user66377

Comment: I have completed building the circuit using the SCR and it works effectively shorting the regulator adjust pin to ground in testing however, when the comparator is first powered on, it starts off with a high blip then goes low but the blip is long enough to trigger the SCR at power on. Adding a capacitor large enough (100uf) to absorb the blip from the opamp output shorted to ground work but this may also be due to using a 741 opamp instead of the 321 you originally suggested :).

Comment: I did however finally get the chance to mock up the circuit and test it by short circuiting the output but this results in heavy draw on the circuit's supply sufficiently dropping power from the comparator circuit and not allowing enough power to light the leds.

Comment: The other thing noticed when triggering the 2N5060, power output of the LM350 drops to 2.8 vdc but directly shorting the LM350 adjust pin to ground results in 1.7 vdc. Trying a 2N2222 or BC547 transistor was not effective and required changing the low and high signals from the comparator output. The 4.7k ohm resistor on the output of the comparator to the SCR trigger was a bit too sensitive, so I added in series a 1M ohm and it worked effectively.

Comment: For the case of using a transistor in place of the scr, you're right to stabilize it with a capacitor for the sake of letting the adjust reset on it's own once the circuit's load was corrected. I know that the lm321 is superior to the 741 op amp. I finally tested with the LM321 once I placed the on a DIP adapter board to use on the breadboard. No more blips from the comparator. I was shooting myself in the foot so to speak :D

Comment: Since the load on the circuit's power supply is still high in the event of a short circuit. So low voltage but high current is the result. It appears that protection in the form of current regulation may be in order, like the shunt that KryanF suggested. More experimenting to come...